# How can I make my wireless keyboard respond faster

Tags: usb, keyboard, wireless-keyboard

I am using an A4tech wireless keyboard(GL-6) with my windows xp.I am experiencing some issues with  my keyboard.Very often during my typing, sometimes it doesn't respond to my key-presses and sometimes it produces repeated keys.I have tried many solutions like removing USB hub,removing other usb keyboards+mouse but none of this is working.

Comment: Did you tried the trival things like new batteries or more the keyboard closer to the USB Receiver?

Comment: Yes! I have replaced my batteries with new ones.And Yes I have moved it closer to USB receiver.But none of this is working.Actually my keyboard works perfectly when I just login.But after 30-40 minutes of typing these kind of problems starts to appear.